# Navigation between DIV's with triggers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have three DIVs with the CSS "clip-path" attribute, which include low polygon shapes and text based titles.

I want to create divergent navigation (like a basic slider) between these DIVs and while titles are changing with a simple animation (fade-in and -out, etc.) shapes are transforming each other at same time.

Shapes will be static layers which change position when navigation is triggered. But titles are dynamically changing layers which are different for each DIV.

I had done this in a very simple way at first by assigning the "hover" state to the DIV, but since I do not know JS, I can only do this with "toggle", as you can see in the example.

But I want it to work with triggers like "click", "mousewheel" and the arrow keys.

Animations, transformations and other similar things about CSS are not a problem, I just have to learn how to create this navigation system between DIV's.

```js
 $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.container').toggleClass('moved');
 })
```

```css
.container {
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 60%;
  position: relative;
}
.poly {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .75s ease-in-out;
}
.poly:first-child {
  clip-path: polygon(45% 25%, 40% 70%, 75% 30%);
}
.moved .poly:first-child {
  clip-path: polygon(35% 50%, 55% 65%, 90% 45%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">Move It</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="poly"></div>
</div>
```

Here is Jsfiddle file https://jsfiddle.net/Lsuw3L9z/

Comment: Please try to be more specific, working example and simple question will be much more helpfull than wall of plain text. Also your title is not giving any clue of what you want to do. Title should be a actualy question

Comment: "As you can see in the example" - what example? I think you forgot to include one.

Comment: Sorry guys I was not aware of we cant add codepen link so I was writing the codes.

Comment: Heres a jsfiddle. though im still not sure what the question actually is. https://jsfiddle.net/Lsuw3L9z/

Comment: As a side note, the `clip-path` property is not well supported, particularly by Microsoft browsers. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: We need more information about what the difference is between what you have and what you want. You say there's three `div`s, but your example only has two, and there doesn't seem to be any "titles" involved.